# Reconstruct a distribution using summary statistics and percentiles

Tags: statistics, random

I have a summary statistics and various percentiles generated from a data set. This include: mean, std, min, p10, p25, p50, p75, p90, p95, max

Is there a way to reconstruct the data distribution from the numbers above?

I tried generating subsets of the distribution that would satisfy the percentiles ( 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547364/generate-distribution-given-percentile-ranks)

That worked fairly well for examples like:

mean, std, min, p10, p25, p50, p75, p90, p95, max

63.6118, 36.1138, 0, 0, 45.8822, 75, 100, 100, 100, 100

and very poorly for examples like:

mean, std, min, p10, p25, p50, p75, p90, p95, max

0.0346, 0.8115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0016, 0.0092, 0.0338, 29.4324

Is there a method that would work well without having assumptions about the skewness of the underlying distribution or its modality (e.g., unimodal vs multi-modal)?

The overall goal here is to try to generate a data sample from this unknown distribution that would match the given summary statistics.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for your question Somos! I want to generate a random sample from that distribution that would match with the given summary statistics.

Comment: Please add your comment to the body of your question so that it is clear what you want to accompish. Also, note that any finite number of statistics does not determine a distribution uniquely **unless** it is known to be a membor of a parametric family. Also, please state clearly what you mean by a method works poorly.

Comment: If you have a sufficiently fine grid of quantiles for a sample of size $n,$ then you have in effect the inverse empirical CDF (inverse ECDF) of the sample. Applying the inverse ECDF to a random sample of size $n$ from $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ will give a reasonable facsimile of the original sample. // But you're expectations must be realistic. Even if you knew the $n$ original data values were a random from, say $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\sigma=15),$ you could not re-generate a sample of size $n$ that's an _exact_ match for the original.

Comment: Thank you BruceET! Very helpful. Certainly, I won't expect to get an exact match.